# Catalog XML Display

Tags: xml, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I can't figure out why my photos are in a column under my product info, i need these in one row, and i need the photos to be 60% of that row and the info to be 40%.

[photo for reference][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMD7C.png

I changed the columns, the info size was 7 and the photos were 5 so i switched them and it did this, and stayed even after i switched them back.

````
                            <container name="product.inner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                                <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media product-img-box clearfix col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" before="product.info.main" />
                                <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main product-shop col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" after="product.info.media">
                                    <container name="product.shopcontent" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-shop-content clearfix">
                                        <container name="product.content.left" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="shop-content-left">
                                            <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" before="product.info.stock.sku">
                                                    <arguments>
                                                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                                                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                                                    </arguments>
                                                </block>
                                                <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                                                    <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                                                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="product.price.final">
                                                        <arguments>
                                                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                                                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                                                            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                                                        </arguments>
                                                    </block>
                                                </container>
                                            </container>
                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" before="product.info.sku">
                                                <arguments>
                                                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                                                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                                                </arguments>
                                            </block>
                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="page.main.title" />
                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.review">
                                                <arguments>
                                                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                                                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                                                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                                                    <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                                                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                                                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                                                </arguments>
                                            </block>
                                            <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
                                            <!-- <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                                                <move element="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" destination="product.info" label="Product View Extra Hint"/>
                                            </block> -->
                                        </container>
                                    </container> 
                                </container>
                            </container> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

NVM! I accidentally commented out an extra closing tag and erased another closing tag. I figured it out.